# Как правильнее будет реализовать вспомогательные функции Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Доброго времени суток!
Задался двумя вопросами по реализации некоторых функций. Не могу определиться, как верно их создать - компонентом, либо виджетом, либо вовсе отдельным классом. Подробнее ниже.

---

1. Как лучше создавать дополнительные вспомогательные функции, которые могут использоваться в разных контроллерах?

**Пример:**

У нас есть функция `alert()`, которая отвечает за запись оповещений(запись в БД для дальнейшего вывода) о некоторых событиях, которые могут быть в разных контроллерах(к)/моделях(м). К примеру: зарегистрировался новый пользователь(К: UserController, М: User), оставлен комментарий в блоге(К: BlogController, М: Article).

Как лучше реализовать подобное? В виде компонента? Либо просто создать какой-либо независимый отдельный класс?

---

2. Как лучше реализовать вывод мета-данных, подключение сторонних модулей?

**Пример:**

Допустим, у нас есть в базе данных 2 таблицы:
1 - с которой нужно выводить мета-данных для определенных экшенов.
2 - с которой нужно выводить сторонние скрипты(к примеру, jivo-чат, метрика и т.д.), которыми пользователь управляет в панели управления.

Каким образом лучше реализовать? По-сути, для HTML-представления используются виджеты же, верно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вся логика проекта должна выполняться либо в моделях, либо в функциональных классах.
По этому оба ваших пункта правильнее всего будет вынести в компонент, он автономный, доступ к нему можно получить из любой части вашего проекта, он имеет свою логику и по необходимости свое представление.
Виджеты представляют собой многоразовые строительные блоки, т.е. какой-то html код который вы используете многоразово по всему проекту. По этому вывод к примеру тех же метаданных можно реализовать с помощью виджета для каждой страницы вашего сайта